# where are google chrome sync bookmarks stored?

Tags: google-chrome

I need to access a website from my bookmarks but i don't want to sync my bookmarks to another persons computer.. Once i was able to open the stored bookmarks in Google docs, but there is no way to access the bookmarks now.

Is there a way to access my synced bookmarks without syncing ?

Comment: Technically, this should be possible. Image you would have set up a new Chrome installation without any bookmarks and connect to your Google Account then. The browser would just download all bookmarks stored online. You could write an application which approaches the Google server like a Chrome browser without bookmarks.

Answer (score 2):

The google documentation says nothing about being able to access them,
Also, when you go to "Manage accounts" in you google account it says:

> Chrome sync Nothing interesting here.
>   Stop sync and delete data from Google
>   Chrome privacy policy

So I guess it's impossible to do through their website without syncing... You can try syncing, copying all the bookmarks you need, and stop the syncing.

If you have some kind of remote access to your computer you can go to the Chrome data folder, in Windows 7 it's located in:
C:\Users\USERNAMEHERE\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data
Maybe try messing around there... there are files with the name "bookmarks" and they're not encrypted or anything...

Comment: too bad.. for now there seems no options but to sync.

Comment: Well just sync, copy the stuff you need, unsync and delete the stuff you don't want to keep on that computer