# Sync Google Chrome Bookmarks Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, bookmarks

I have been trying to find some way to read Google Chrome's bookmarks (not Google's Bookmarks) from Android. I'm trying to develop an application that does not needs to install a plugin on the browser to sync. the bookmarks. By the way, I know that an application called CMarks already does what I need, but I want to learn how to do it myself.

The problem is that I haven't found a way to do it. My question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315545/where-are-google-chrome-sync-bookmarks-stored) one I think, but it doesn't have an "answer".

I've found [this](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/sync), which is supposed to be the way Google Chrome's syncs. the bookmarks, but I don't see a way to implement it (there are no OAuth endpoints or anything I understand).

If someone could point me in the right direction (tutorials, manuals, etc.) would be great. Everything I've found on Google was about google Chrome plugins, but not about an external application (Java, Android, C++, etc.).

I've used fiddler to see where GChrome connects when it syncs., and it seems to connect to Google Talk.